# Bootstrap: splitting a box in to 3's

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I have a block of HTML thats like this:

```
<div class="info-box-content">
    <span class="info-box-text">CPU Traffic</span>
    <span class="info-box-number">{!! $cpuUseage !!}<small>%</small></span>
</div>
```

The above box currently displays like this - as seen [here](https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html):

[image]

How could I split the box into 3 seperate boxes so I can display some more knowledgeable stats within the one box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

```
<div class="info-box-content row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <span class="info-box-text">CPU Traffic</span>
     <span class="info-box-number">10<small>%</small></span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <span class="info-box-text">RAM Traffic</span>
     <span class="info-box-number">50<small>%</small></span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <span class="info-box-text">HDD Traffic</span>
     <span class="info-box-number">90<small>%</small></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use grid. Here's a useful link

https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/